# In a quartz cron expression, does */30 mean anything?

Tags: cron, quartz

I have encountered this Quartz @Schedule annotation in code I have been given to maintain:

@Schedule(second="*/30", minute="*", hour="*", persistent=false)

Regarding the seconds value, does */30 make sense? I assume the intent is to have the job run every 30 seconds, which according to documentation I think should be 0/30. How will the scheduler interpret */30? Could it cause problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Regarding the seconds value, does */30 make sense?

`*/30` is a valid expression and it means ***every 30 seconds***.